# Labeling points in ListPointPlot3D with mutiple data sets using a list of labels

Tags: plotting, labeling

> (*I am trying to label points in ListPointPlot3D. I have multiple data sets. I was able to label points in one data set but that does not work for multiple data sets as in the code below.If I have one data set, LabelingFunction->Callout works but not if I have two data sets. Also if there is a better method of labeling the points without Callout's curvy pointer line that would be great.*)

```
data1={{302, 0.0001, 0.17}, {408, 0.000085, 0.17}, {383, 0.000094, 
0.13}, {326, 0.000072, 0.14}, {310, 0.00005, 0.1}, {308, 0.00011, 
0.16}, {317, 0.00008, 0.23}};
data2={{161, 0.00061, 0.25}, {297, 0.000055, 0.046}, {199, 0.00071, 
0.27}, {169, 0.00012, 0.26}, {159, 0.00032, 0.48}, {213, 0.0012, 
0.24}, {184, 0.00063, 0.28}};
labels = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7"};
labels1={"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"};
ListPointPlot3D[{data1, data2} -> labels1, 
LabelingFunction -> Callout, 
PlotRange -> {{100, 450.}, {0, .0015}, {0, .8}}, 
PlotStyle -> (Directive[PointSize[.02], Opacity[2.8], 
AbsoluteThickness[3.0], #] & /@ {Hue[0.58, 1, 1], 
Hue[0., 1, 1]}), 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontSize -> 12, FontColor -> Black], 
PlotLegends -> 
Placed[LineLegend[{"data1", "data2"}, LegendLabel -> " ", 
LabelStyle -> {Helvetica, Bold, 12}, 
LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}], {.75, .9}], 
AxesLabel -> {" X", "Y", "Z"}, 
PlotLabel -> Style["", FontSize -> 12, FontColor -> Black]]
```

Comment: Would this change it for the better or worse? `ListPointPlot3D[{data1 -> labels1, data2 -> labels1}...` ?

Comment: or `ListPointPlot3D[{data1, data2}, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Callout[#, Automatic] &)...` which is not very readabale.

Comment: MMA version 13.0 seems to work.

Comment: ListPointPlot3D[{data1 -> labels1, data2 -> labels1} does not work.

Comment: ListPointPlot3D[{data1, data2},   LabelingFunction -> (Callout[#, Automatic] &) wont work because I want my labels to be used (not a sequence)

Comment: Did my syntax work with MMA 13?

Comment: I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Nbc.png) for the two cases. Notice that I have put `...` in the comments above assuming that you can make this change (only) and use the rest of the syntax as is.

Comment: ListPointPlot3D[{data1 -> labels1, data2 -> labels1} works with MMA 13 not MMA 12.

Comment: My version is 12.2.0 Win7-x64.

Comment: @Syed Thanks, not sure why it didn't work with version 12.3 ( I think that is what I had). I upgraded to 13 and it works.